My Omdb API is Giving no Result on my Console in React
I am using react, right I tried using this API, but it didn't work although it was showing results just fine in my Postman so I don't know what's the issue.
const average = (arr) =>
  arr.reduce((acc, cur, i, arr) => acc + cur / arr.length, 0);
const key = "b5873f01";

export default function App() {
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
  const [watched, setWatched] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=${key}&s=avatar`)
      .then((res) => {
        if (!res.ok) {
          throw new Error("Network response was not ok");
        }
        return res.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data); // Log the fetched data
        setMovies(data.Search);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error fetching movie data:", error);
      });
  }, []);


Assuming that you're importing useState and useEffect into your component (and returning something) this code works - I've just tested it. Are you getting any errors in your console at all?

Just need to use https instead of http in the URL

@OnurDoğan - that's not necessary.

adding s didn't work

As I pointed out your code works. @abdojama, so something else is going wrong.
